# Display dropdown list which User's belongs branch in Laravel8 relation

Tags: laravel

I'm studying relation in Laravel8.

I would like to make data post page. Currently it works fine but I would like to little update that is "relation"

- User must login system before post data.
- The system look user's branch then display dropdown list as related Partner's table's branch name.

Each User belong to branch (br)
For example A user name is Mike. Mike works USA branch.
As you see this images below(2 tables). Mike is related USA branch.so below dropdown list will appears.
[image]
[image]

> [Partner table] only 'USA' record will show up.

```
<option value="HR cafe" @if(old('partner')=='HR cafe') selected  @endif>HR cafe</option>
<option value="HM store" @if(old('partner')=='HM store') selected  @endif>HM store</option>
```

so I wrote below and I know it's totally not enough at all. Could you teach me right code please?

```
public function create()
{
    // If user's branch is matched partner's branch
    if(Auth::user()->br = partner()->br){
    // Display dropdown list
    $partner = Tag::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
    }
    return view('products.create',compact('products'));
    
}
```

Comment: why cant you use partner id in users table instead of  br .so that you can write relationship

Comment: Thank you for helping me every time.
USA branch has many partners. each branch has lots of name.

Comment: better if you show tables relationship with structure so some one can help you

Comment: You mean entity-relationship Diagram? sorry I explain is complicated. I would like to branch and brach mached record will show up.

Comment: if(Auth::user()->br =Auth::user()->partner()->br){

Comment: Thank you! I see This is the way! I will work on little more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234763/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-bluetail).